# How to write properties in application.properties using Maven Archetype

Tags: java, maven, properties, maven-archetype

I'm creating an archetype so my team can generate a couple of projects and I've run into a problem.

I'm trying to write a property into my application.properties file and I can't seem to make it work. What I have now is this:

```
application.name=my-app-name <--- this should take the artifactId name
logging.file=logback-spring.xml
```

I've tried using ${artifactId} but it didn't work. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: editted for focusing only on the main goal.

Comment: Are you using `spring-boot-starter-parent`? If not you have a few more things to do, this link might help https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven

Comment: I do have spring-boot-starter-parent on my pom.xml . But isn't that used for dynamic properties like the ones I have between @@? 
I need to set the spring.application.name upon project generation, not when starting the application. 
Sorry if I'm not understanding what you mean and thanks for your response.
PD: Editted the main question to focus only on maven archetype and not on Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if ${artifactId} doesn't work, probably your archetype doesn't have the filtered activated for resources, you can activate it adding the following conf to your `archetype-metadata.xml`

```
<archetype-descriptor>
  <fileSets>
    ...
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false" encoding="UTF-8">
        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
    </fileSet>
    ...
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!